# How to find the largest digit of a given number

Tags: c

My problem is that I am converting a given octal number to binary and the binary to a hexadecimal. And to display the hexadecimal, I am using %lx. but I want to find the largest of this hexadecimal. Is there a way I can store the %lx value and then run the largest function?

```
long long convertOctalToBinary(int octalNumber);
int convertBinarytoHex(long long binary);
int largest(long int hex);

int main()
{
int octalNumber;
long long number;
long int result;
int temp;
int large;


printf("Enter an octal number: ");
scanf("%d", &octalNumber);
number = convertOctalToBinary(octalNumber);
printf("number : %d\n", number);
result = convertBinarytoHex(number);
printf("result : %lX\n", result);
large = largest(temp);
printf("large : %lX\n", large);
}



int convertBinarytoHex(long long number)
{

long int hexvalue = 0;
int i = 1;
int r; //declare variables

while (number != 0) //if binary number is not equal to 0 then following instructions will execute
{
    r = number % 10; //by performing modulo we get remainder
    hexvalue = hexvalue + r * i; //for first digit i =1 as binavalue*2^0,binvalue*2^1
    i = i * 2; //i value multiplied with 2 for next iteration,for next iterations it becmoes 2^1,2^2,2^3
    number = number / 10; //now get reamaing binary value
}
return hexvalue;
}

int largest(long int hex)
{
 int p,i=0,digit,large=0;//variables

 p=hex;//storing original value entered by user to variable p

 while(hex>0)
 {
    digit=hex%10;//finding digit

    if(digit>large)//checking condition for large
    large=digit;

 hex = hex / 10;//dividing number by 10
 }

 return large;
 }
```

Comment: Only one kind of number exists in computers and that is binary numbers. Everything else is _user presentations of binary numbers_. 

Therefore it doesn't make sense to "convert from octal to binary" etc, because every variable in your C program is binary, always. 

What you can do is to use another number base when you need to take a number from the user, or present a number to the user. For example you can read a number that the user prints in octal using `scanf("%o", &octalNumber);` and you can display a number as octal using `printf(%o", octalNumber);`.

Comment: And this is the reason why we read/write "plain" integers with `%d`, which stands for decimal, base 10. Meaning that the input/output will be in decimal format.

Comment: the problem is that given a octal number by a user, we need to show the highest hexadecimal digit in the octal

Comment: So i have a function that takes the given octal, converts to binary and displays it at hexa

Comment: Now could you tell me how to store this %lx and display the max of this?

Comment: What is "the highest hex digit in the octal" even supposed to mean? That can be interpreted in many different ways.

Comment: Your question makes little sense or it is very poorly worded. Maybe you should show us some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Okay say the user inputs a octal 543 which converts to 163 in hexadecimal. I need to be able to print 6 as the output. In the code, I run a function to convert 543 to binary and then to hexadecimal. The function to convert 543 to hexadecimal stores the value as 355 and to get the hex value I use %ld. Now when I run the largest function which picks the largest digit, I get the output to be 5. I need to be able to run this function on 163 instead

Comment: @AbhijitReddy please [edit] your question and put all relevant information _there_

Comment: Your format specifiers for `printf` are wrong. `number` is `long long` while `large` ist not long at all. You might want to check your `l`prefixes.

Comment: You probably need to use `sprintf()` to format the hex value into a string.  You can then analyze the string to find the largest hex digit, and you can also print the string, of course.

Comment: You're probably best of converting into strings.

Comment: @AbhijitReddy so your problem actually boils down to two questions: __1__ : _How can I find the largest digit of the hexadecimal representation of a number?_ __2__ : _How can I read a number the user enters in octal ?_ Please confirm.

Comment: p=Hex; why is that for ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char largestdigit(const char *buffer)
{
  char largest = 0;       // largest digit (initially 0)

  char c;
  while (c = *buffer++)   // loop until we reach end of string
  {
    if (c > largest)
      largest = c;
  }

  return largest;
}

int main()
{
  int number;
  printf("Enter an octal number: ");
  scanf("%o", &number);                  // read number entered in octal

  char hexbuffer[50];
  sprintf(hexbuffer, "%x", number);      // output number in hexadecimal to hexbuffer

  char large = largestdigit(hexbuffer);  // find largest digit in hexbuffer
  printf("largest digit of hexadecimal representation (%x) of octal number %o : %c\n", number, number, largestdigit(hexbuffer));
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter an octal number: 543
largest digit of hexadecimal representation (163) of octal number 543 : 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you have completely wrong approach.

First, storing representations in number types makes no sense, unless you really need high performance. It is likely to cause bugs though. `int` stores a *number* and not it's representation. You can however tell `scanf` to treat the input as an octal number. Just use `scanf("%o", &var)`.

If the problem is to find the biggest digit, you're much better of converting it into a digit array, aka a string representation. Here is some code that converts an int to a string in an arbitrary base.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Will work for base 2-36. Well, it works for higher bases too, but 
   it can be iffy to interpret the result. */
void intToStr(int number, int base,  char * dest)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (number != 0) {
        int rem=number%base;
        char digit = rem>9 ? rem+'a'-10 : rem+'0';
        dest[index++]=digit;
        number/=base;
    }
    dest[index]='\0';
    for(int i=0; i<index-1; i++) {
        char tmp = dest[i];
        dest[i]=dest[index-i-1];
        dest[index-i-1]=tmp;
    }
}

char highestDigit(const char *str)
{
    char c=str[0];
    int index=0;
    while(str[index]) {
        c=c<str[index] ? str[index] : c;
        index++;
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int n;
    printf("Enter a octal number: ");
    scanf("%o", &n);

    printf("\nBase Value Highest digit\n");        
    for(int i=2; i<17; i++) {
        intToStr(n, i, str);
        printf("%d: %s %c\n", i, str, highestDigit(str));
    }
}
```

Some output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter an octal number: 100

Base Value Highest digit
2: 1000000 1
3: 2011 2
4: 1000 1
5: 224 4
6: 144 4
7: 121 2
8: 100 1
9: 71 7
10: 64 6
11: 59 9
12: 54 5
13: 4c c
14: 48 8
15: 44 4
16: 40 4
```

Comment: You can compare any numeric type in C, though you might have to coerce a `float` to compare to an `int`. Since `long` and `int` are both fixed types you can compare them directly.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin True, but what is the point?